# Webpack config trouble

Tags: webpack

I get this error when I try to run Webpack and I don't know why. 
Using Webpack 4. Don't know why it's not working any suggestions.
I was following survive Webpack book and I'm sure I did the correct steps.
I tried changing the position and moving it around. I tried also removing the braces at the end of loadCSS but that does not call the function then.

```
[nodemon] watching: webpack.config.js
[nodemon] starting `webpack-dev-server --env development`
/Users/oscar/batcave/webpack-demo/webpack.config.js:20
  parts.loadCSS(),
        ^

TypeError: parts.loadCSS is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/oscar/batcave/webpack-demo/webpack.config.js:20:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Users/oscar/batcave/webpack-demo/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:133:13)
    at requireConfig (/Users/oscar/batcave/webpack-demo/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:135:6)
```

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const SystemBellPlugin = require('system-bell-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');

const parts = './config/webpack.parts';
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

const commonConfig = merge([
  {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'webpack demo',
      }),
      new SystemBellPlugin(),
      new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
      new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  parts.loadCSS(),
]);

const productionConfig = merge([]);

const developmentConfig = merge([parts.devServer]);

module.exports = mode => {
  if (mode === 'production') {
    return merge(commonConfig, productionConfig, { mode });
  }
  return merge(commonConfig, developmentConfig, { mode });
};
```

webpack.parts.js

```
exports.devServer = ({ host, port } = {}) => ({
  devServer: {
    stats: 'errors-only',
    host,
    port,
    open: true,
    overlay: true,
  },
});

exports.loadCSS = ({ include, exclude } = {}) => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include,
        exclude,

        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Comment: May be try importing parts like ``import * as parts from ./config/webpack.parts`` ???

Comment: if i use import it says SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change `exports` -> `module.exports`

```
module.exports.devServer = ({ host, port } = {}) => ({
  devServer: {
    stats: 'errors-only',
    host,
    port,
    open: true,
    overlay: true,
  },
});

module.exports.loadCSS = ({ include, exclude } = {}) => ({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include,
        exclude,

        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

**EDIT**

```
const parts = require('./config/webpack.parts');
```

[Link document](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

Comment: doesn't seem to have helped

Comment: Can you try with `const parts = require('./config/webpack.parts');`?

Comment: You can use preference link from http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: yeah, that seems to have worked but why does it work this way and not the other way?

Comment: You can wrap 2 function in Class, and export class 
`export default class { ... };`

`//------ main2.js ------`
`import MyClass from 'MyClass';`
`let inst = new MyClass();`